# what address to use in inet_pton?

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, ip

I am beginner for IP/TCP, but reading [Addison Wesley : UNIX
Network Programming
Volume 1](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Unix-Network-Programming-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0131411551), I have the following code:

```
#include "unp.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd, n;
    char recvline[MAXLINE + 1];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        err_quit("usage: main <IPaddress>");
    }

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        err_sys("socket error");
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        err_quit("inet_pton error for %s", argv[1]);
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (SA *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        err_sys("connect error");
    }

    while ((n = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        recvline[n] = 0;
        if (fputs(recvline, stdout) == EOF)
        {
            err_sys("fputs error");
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Now from the book, they run it as

```
solaris % a.out 206.168.112.96
```

If I look-up my address:

```
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin/1$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 15419  bytes 1627065 (1.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15419  bytes 1627065 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 2a00:1028:8d1b:f32a:8ddb:cc89:8404:e9dc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a00:1028:8d1b:f32a:c84a:2566:28f5:81e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::2954:989:452f:c90f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5c:3a:45:55:ae:b5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1095391  bytes 1521941184 (1.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 392567  bytes 53028207 (53.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I assume this is my IPv4 address `10.0.0.5`, so if I try to run the code above:

```
./a.out 10.0.0.5
connect error: Connection refused
```

I got connection refused. Am I using the right address?, From the book, they used something starting with 206... What address should I use that will be parsed by `inet_pton`?

Comment: The problem is not with the IP itself. It is with the fact that you are trying to connect to an IP that is not running a listening [daytime server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol) on port 13. You can’t connect to a non-existent server.  That is (one of) the reasons that “connection refused” means - the connection reached the target IP, but the target port is not open at that IP.

Comment: If I establish one with `nc`, the netcat server is still waiting for something even after connection was established (`sudo nc -v -l -s127.0.0.1 -p13`). But I never got the date printed out. How to stop listening and send the data to print from the client side (the c file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give yourself something to connect with locally first. Try `nc -v -l 13` to run netcat listening on port 13, for example, before running your program in a separate terminal. Sorry, I don't have enough rep to only comment.

Comment: After listing from netcat to localhsot (127.0.0.1), the connection was established. But the datetime was not even then printed. I got this: `Connection received on localhost 51188`, but then waiting. how to end the listing and get output from the client side (the c executable)?

Comment: the use of netcat was only to create a temporary example server to test socket. you will need to enable daytime server through inetd or xinetd to receive the date and time response

Comment: @milanHrabos: pivoc is absolutely correct: `"Give yourself something to connect with"`. 
 "nc -v -l 13" is one good suggestion.  It will let the test client "connect" ...but it won't give "time".  "time.nist.gov" (`132.163.96.4`) is another alternative: https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi.  Please be sure to "upvote" and "accept" pivoc's response.

Answer (score 0):

Use your localmachine Ip address.
or use default localhost ip address : 127.0. 0.1.
This address 127.0. 0.1 is the standard address for IPv4.

Comment: Or ::1 for the IPv6 example.